# mysql query; rename 2 values from single column

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this.
I am trying to query values from column `id5` and give them new names.

```
 id      id2   id3 id4   id5
----------------------------
174977  20214 209 8278  1
174976  20214 209 8277  abc123
174975  20214 209 8276  33333
174974  20214 209 8275  My Name
```

here is my query

```
select a.id5 as qty, b.id5 as itemnum 
from mytable a where id4 = 8278, 
mytable b where id4 = 8276
```

so that I get an output like this.

```
qty      itemnum  
----------------
1        33333
```

Can anyone help please?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN id4 = 8278 THEN id5 END) qty
     , MAX(CASE WHEN id4 = 8276 THEN id5 END) itemnum
  FROM mytable
 GROUP 
    BY id2
     , id3;
```

Comment: I dont think you need the group by

Comment: it worked as I wished for without group by, thank you!